# UIviewcontroller in Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I want to add an UIViewController subclass to my Project , but I didn't find it when I click on "add new file"

Comment: So you choose IOS-> cocoa touch-> Objective-c Class-> Subclass of UIViewcontroller ?

Answer (score 1):

Choose Objective-C class under Cocoa Touch then type UIViewController in the text field that says "Subclass of".

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode** -> **File** -> **New** -> **File...** -> then select Objective-C Class under Cocoa Touch and then -> **Next** ->  type your class name and select `UIViewController` from dropDown

[image]